# Animate div when text in div is updated

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a HTML, CSS and AngularJS application.
I have a `div` in my html where I display some text as shown below:

`<div id='myDiv'>{{myScope.details}}</div>`

When I `change myScope.details` variable from inside the controller, I want to animate `myDiv` when I am updating the `myScope.details`. In short, when the text inside the `div` is updated, I want the `div` to animate. How can this be done using HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar before, this directive will work:

```
app.directive("animateOnChange", function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            element.addClass('animate-change');
            scope.$watch(attr.animateOnChange, function(newvalue, oldvalue) {
                if (newvalue != oldvalue) {
                    element.removeClass("changed");
                    $timeout(function() {
                        element.addClass("changed");
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

And some animation in your css:

```
.changed {
    -webkit-animation: highlight-fade 1s ease-in 1;
    animation: highlight-fade 1s ease-in 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes highlight-fade {
    0% {border: 3px solid yellow;}
    100% {border: 3px solid transparent;}
}
@keyframes highlight-fade {
    0% {border: 3px solid yellow;}
    100% {border: 3px solid transparent;}
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywL9x8cb/3/) for an example.